# How do I pass a variable defined as (Entry.get()) from one function to another?

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

How do I pass the (Answer) variable from creatLabels function to check function?

```py
def createLabels(Ques):

    AnswerINP = Entry(root)

    AnswerINP.grid(column=3, sticky=W )

    Answer = AnswerINP.get() 

    Checkbutton = tk.Button(root, text="CHECK", command= check)

    Checkbutton.grid()


def check ():

       r=requests.get('https://opentdb.com/api.phpamount='+TextINP1.get()+'&difficul)
        res = r.json ()

        for data in res ['results']:

                if Answer.title()== data["correct_answer"]:

                        print("Correct")
```

I get that variable Answer is not defined when I write it in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a variable to your check function with the use of a [Lambda Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp). Lambda expressions are basically one line, anonymous(unnamed), functions.

To do this you just have to change you `Checkbuttons` command option to a lambda expression, as well as add the argument to your `check()`, function like so:

```py
def createLabels(Ques):
    AnswerINP = Entry(root)
    AnswerINP.grid(column=3, sticky=W )
    Answer = AnswerINP.get() 

    Checkbutton = tk.Button(root, text="CHECK", command=lambda a=Answer: check(a))

    Checkbutton.grid()

def check (answer):
    ...
```

This should give you the outcome you want.